# How can I make screen fade to black from terminal rather than just shut off?

Tags: x11, display

I set up a hot corner that uses `xset dpms force off` to turn my display off. However, I want the  fade-out effect to black that OSX has. How can I achieve this with a terminal command?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use *xscreensaver*. You can configure it with

```
$ xscreensaver-demo
```

to use a fade animation and then then start a blank screensaver and/or turn the monitor off.

Once configured, you can activate it with

```
$ xscreensaver-command -lock
```

One downside to this method is that it could interfere with using xscreensaver as your regular screensaver.

Comment: Is there a similar option with `cinnamon-screensaver`? That is what my distro uses, and I do not want to install `xscreensaver`, which may interfere with that.

Comment: According to the [Man Page](https://manned.org/cinnamon-screensaver-command/3e289d00), `cinnamon-screensaver` comes with a `cinnamon-screensaver-command` option which has an `--activate` option that could be used to blank the screen. 

I'm not sure if `cinnamon-screensaver` also has a fade option. You may have to check the options yourself.